# Determine the size of string in a particular cell in dataframe: R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

In a data frame, I have a column (type: chr) that contains answers separated by a comma. I want to create another column based on the size of the string and award points. For example, some of the entries in a column are:

Column1 
word1,word2,word3 
word1,word2 
word1

Now, for the first cell, I want the size of the cell to be evaluated as 3 (as it contains three distinct word and there are no duplicates in the cell values). I'm not sure how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to split the column with `strsplit` into a `list` of `vector`s, get the `unique` elements by looping over the `list` with `lapply` and get the `lengths`

```
df1$Size <- lengths(lapply(strsplit(df1$Column1, ",\\s*"), unique))
```

---

Another option is `separate_rows` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(Column1) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise(Size = n_distinct(Column1), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  select(Size) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .)
```

-output

```
#            Column1 Size
#1 word1,word2,word3    3
#2       word1,word2    2
#3             word1    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Column1 = c('word1,word2,word3', 'word1,word2', 'word1'))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Original Answer**:

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Lengths = str_count(Column1, ",") + 1)
```

**Edit**:

I hadn't noticed the OP requirements properly (about non-duplicates). As @Onyambu pointed out in the comments, **this chunk will only works if there are no duplicated words** in data.

It basically counts how many words there are.

Comment: Note this is will not give the correct result when there are duplicates. eg `word1, word1, word2, word2` should give a result of 2 and not 4

Comment: Yeah, it's true! One should be sure about the data structure...

Comment: OP did mention that they only wanted to count the non duplicated values. Check the answer given by @akrun

Comment: @Onyambu, I've really missed that part. So this answer, although works for the data example, isn't correct at all. Gonna remove it.

Comment: Done! Thanks again!